# set member function of the schmatrix class in cvm library is throwing an exception but why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I've created a mex function through adding the following code in `mx_minimum_power.cpp`

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "cvm.h"
#include "blas.h"
#include "cfun.h"

using std::complex;
using namespace cvm;

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    const int arraysize = 62172;
    const int matrixDimention = 3;
    float *inMatrixA11 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    complex<float> *inMatrixA12 = (complex<float> *)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    complex<float> *inMatrixA13 = (complex<float> *)mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    float *inMatrixA22 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
    complex<float> *inMatrixA23 = (complex<float> *)mxGetPr(prhs[4]);
    float *inMatrixA33 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
    basic_schmatrix< float, complex<float> > A(matrixDimention);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        A.set(1, 1, inMatrixA11[i]);
        A.set(1, 2, inMatrixA12[i]);
        A.set(1, 3, inMatrixA13[i]);
        A.set(2, 2, inMatrixA22[i]);
        A.set(2, 3, inMatrixA23[i]);
        A.set(3, 3, inMatrixA33[i]);
    }
}
```

And then I've created `mx_minimum_power.mexw64` through entering the following code in matlab command line.

```
mex -g mx_minimum_power.cpp cvm_em64t_debug.lib
```

But seems that the [set member function of basic_schmatrix class](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/classbasic__schmatrix.html#a7fbedcbcd79c674566d20d43ff703304) is throwing a [cvmexception](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/classcvmexception.html) at 27th line `A.set(1, 1, inMatrixA11[i]);`

I really don't understand the reason for this exception regarding the fact that I have used indices `1,1` that are within the range `[1,4)` in [CVM0 based indexing](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/cvm_8h_source.html#l00052)
And also considering that just before running the 27th line `A.set(1, 1, inMatrixA11[i]);` we have following values for `A11[0],A12[0],A13[0],A22[0],A23[0],A33[0]`:

[image]

that are just as expected.

[image]

And the following memory is allocated for the `hermitian matrix A`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because we have the following code in lines 48 to 53 of the `cvm.h` file:

```
// 5.7 0-based indexing
#if defined (CVM_ZERO_BASED)
#   define CVM0 TINT_ZERO //!< Index base, 1  by default or 0 when \c CVM_ZERO_BASED is defined
#else
#   define CVM0 TINT_ONE  //!< Index base, 1  by default or 0 when \c CVM_ZERO_BASED is defined
#endif
```

That makes `CVM0 = 1` by default. So if we press the `Step Into(F11)` button at the specified line two times, we will get into line 34883 of the file `cvm.h`:

```
basic_schmatrix& set(tint nRow, tint nCol, TC c) throw(cvmexception)
{
    this->_set_at(nRow - CVM0, nCol - CVM0, c);
    return *this;
}
```

Press `Step Into(F11)` at line `this->_set_at(nRow - CVM0, nCol - CVM0, c);` and you'll go to the definition of the function `_set_at`:

```
// sets both elements to keep matrix hermitian, checks ranges
// zero based
void _set_at(tint nRow, tint nCol, TC val) throw(cvmexception)
{
    _check_lt_ge(CVM_OUTOFRANGE_LTGE1, nRow, CVM0, this->msize() + CVM0);
    _check_lt_ge(CVM_OUTOFRANGE_LTGE2, nCol, CVM0, this->nsize() + CVM0);
    if (nRow == nCol && _abs(val.imag()) > basic_cvmMachMin<TR>()) { // only reals on main diagonal
        throw cvmexception(CVM_BREAKS_HERMITIANITY, "real number");
    }
    this->get()[this->ld() * nCol + nRow] = val;
    if (nRow != nCol) {
        this->get()[this->ld() * nRow + nCol] = _conjugate(val);
    }
}
```

pressing `Step Over(F10)` button,you'll get the result:

[image]

so in order to get `nRow=1` and `nCol=1` and not `nRow=0` and `nCol=0`, which is out of the range `[1,4)`, you should write that line of code as:

```
A.set(2, 2, inMatrixA11[i]);
```